# What is Explicit synchronization between GPU and CPU

Tags: unity-game-engine, metal

"`Metal` is better than `OpenGL` because of explicit synchronization between GPU and CPU." https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metal_(API)

> What is Explicit synchronization between GPU and CPU ?

Answer (score 5):

Metal was developed to work with Apple hardware, specifically the A7 chip and above. These chips have the CPU and the GPU on the same chip. They share memory space.

One expensive operation in OpenGL is copying buffers of data from the CPU to the GPU. Since these occupy the same space, you don't have to copy data from the CPU to the GPU. The CPU grants the GPU access to the space in memory where the buffers are located so that it can complete work on them without being overwritten by the CPU.

Since OpenGL was created at a time when you couldn't put both the CPU and GPU on the same chip, it wasn't really possible to set up an application that makes the assumption that you don't need to copy memory over, so this created a useless and expensive operation.